# GDAL: Changing a GeoTIFF's Proj.4 K value

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, proj

I have a GeoTIFF that appears to have a broken proj4 K value.
When I run the command: `gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 <Filename>`
I get the output: `+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +k=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs`

My understanding is that k should never be 0.  I assume the author of this GeoTIFF intended for it to be 1.

I tried using following command to set k with no luck: `gdal_translate -projwin_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs" <input file> <output file>`

How can I update the proj4 k value of my GeoTIFF?  Is the proj4 string something that can be changed directly?

Comment: I can't speak to whether that parameter is valid, but you may want to try [gdal_edit](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#cmdoption-a-srs).  There's a description of generally accepted SRS definitions [here](https://gdal.org/programs/raster_common_options.html#cmdoption-t-srs) which includes proj4 strings

Answer (score 1):

The gdal_translate documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html documents also the right option for your use case.

> **-a_srs**  Override the projection for the output file. The may be any of the usual GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT,
>   PROJ.4, EPSG:n or a file containing the WKT. No reprojection is done.

You can also correct the wrong metadata in place with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html but it is a Python script and you must have a working Python environment for GDAL.

Usage:

```
python gdal_edit.py -a_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs" your_tif.tif
```